# Collection as an attribute in EmberJS? (One-to-many relation)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In EmberJS I want to create a model that has a field that is a collection of other models. I figured this would be an easy thing, but I can't get it to work.

My current approach, as demonstrated in the JSFiddle below, is to create the two models (in this case `Foo` and `Bar`) and a collection model for `Bar`s (`BarCollection`). Then I give the `Foo` a `BarCollection` as an attribute, and then try to add `Bar`s to the collection. It doesn't work. No errors are thrown, and the collection exists, but no elements are ever added to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/tbxhQ/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you haven't initialized your concrete `App.BarCollection` instance with a `content` property. This is needed since `Ember.ArrayProxy` proxies to the `content` arrray. If you don't specify one, the proxy doesn't which array it shall use ...

Another issue is that it's a convention to name instances `lowerCase` and classes `UpperCase`. So it's `App.foo`. Also, you should always access properties via `get` and `set`. This guarantees that bindings are resolved correctly.

The result looks like this, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/fpqTv/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    All the bars from {{App.foo.name}}:
    <ul>
        {{#each App.foo.bars }}
            <li>{{this.name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

​
**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Bar = Ember.Object.extend();

App.BarCollection = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend();

App.foo = Ember.Object.create({
    name: 'Fred',
    bars: App.BarCollection.create({
        content: []
    })
});

App.getPath('foo.bars').pushObject(App.Bar.create({
    name: 'bob'
}));​
```

---

As a note: in your case there is no requirement to use an `ArrayProxy` for your `bars` property. A simple JavaScript array does the job as well. So this would be my final suggestion for your posted example, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/CHHXb/:

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Bar = Ember.Object.extend();

App.foo = Ember.Object.create({
    name: 'Fred',
    bars: [],
    addToBars: function(name) {
        this.get('bars').pushObject(App.Bar.create({
            name: name
        }));
    }
});

App.get('foo').addToBars('bob');​
```

Comment: Will the simple JavaScript array still trigger events properly?

Comment: The JavaScript arrays' prototype is extended by Ember.js. So the above code works fine with observers, bindings, ... See http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/7FkcW/